# All Permutations of Names

Tags: c++

I'm needing to write a program that lists all the ways that people can line up for a photo, creating a recursive method to create and output all these possible orderings. It takes in input for these names until -1 is entered and then goes through this function.

My issue is with the output. With three sample names as input, though there will be more added later with other tests, it outputs the initial lines correctly, but the following one of each loop drops the first name. For example:

Input: Julia Lucas Mia

Output I'm getting: (Minus the spaces between lines, sorry for formatting errors)

```
Julia Lucas Mia
Mia Lucas
Lucas Julia Mia
Mia Julia
Mia Julia Lucas
Lucas Julia
```

The output I need to get:

```
Julia Lucas Mia
Julia Mia Lucas
Lucas Julia Mia
Lucas Mia Julia
Mia Julia Lucas
Mia Lucas Julia
```

I don't know what the issue is, so if somebody could help me out that'd be appreciated! Thanks!

Below is my code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;



// TODO: Write method to create and output all permutations of the list of names.
void AllPermutations(const vector<string> &permList, const vector<string> &nameList) {
   
   vector <string> tempVec;
   tempVec.resize(nameList.size());
   vector <string> tempPerm;
   
   unsigned int i;

   string tmpString;
   string tempString;
   
   
    if (nameList.size() == 0){
      for (i = 0;i < permList.size(); i++){
         cout << endl;
         
} 
}
   else {
      for (i = 0; i < nameList.size(); i++){
         tempVec = nameList;
         tmpString = tempVec.at(i);
         cout << tmpString<< " " ; 
         tempPerm.push_back(tmpString);
         tempVec.erase(tempVec.begin() + i);
         AllPermutations(tempPerm, tempVec);
   }
      
  }     
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   vector<string> nameList;
   vector<string> permList;
   string name;

// TODO: Read in a list of names; stop when -1 is read. Then call recursive method.

   cin >> name;
   while (name != "-1"){
      nameList.push_back(name);     
      cin >> name;
      }
   AllPermutations(permList, nameList);
   
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does stepping through the code in a debugger tell you?

Comment: Are you allowed to use `<algorithm>`s from the standard library?

Comment: I'm not allowed to use <algorithm> I believe, because I don't think I can use std::next_permutation.

Comment: What a pity. Do you have a list of functions you can and can not use? It'd be terrible if you come with a good solution that's used something forbidden - or if you come with a bad solution just because you thought that you couldn't use certain stuff.

Comment: No, I don't have a list, but I figured I wouldn't be able to use that due to needing to write an entire function to basically do what std::next_permutation does.

Answer (score 1):

For this, I would use [`std::next_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation):

Repeated calls to it will order the elements in the vector in higher and higher lexicographical order until the permutation results in a lesser lexicographical order than before. It will then return `false` (instead of `true`) which makes it excellent in a `do { ... } while` loop.

Example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> names{
        "Julia", "Lucas", "Mia"
    };

    // sort to make sure we start with the combinaion first in lexicographical order.
    std::sort(names.begin(), names.end());

    do {
        // print what we've got:
        for(auto& n : names) std::cout << n << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';

        // get the next permutation (or quit):
    } while(std::next_permutation(names.begin(), names.end()));
}
```

Output:

```
Julia Lucas Mia 
Julia Mia Lucas 
Lucas Julia Mia 
Lucas Mia Julia 
Mia Julia Lucas 
Mia Lucas Julia
```

Comment: I can't use std::next_permutation, I have to make a whole function that basically does what that does. I did try it, though, the only issue with it is the sorting bit-- it has to be in the same order as it is when input, not lexicographical order

Comment: @t23 For that, just memorize the starting position and loop until you're getting back to it. You can also look at the example implementation (in the link I provided in the answer) to see if you can get any good ideas from that.

Answer (score 1):

So although Uzdavinis' reply is accurate, the workbook requires you to only use one function beyond Main(), so void AllPermutations() along with AllPermutationsImpl() won't push through.
This code passes the requirements:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void AllPermutations (vector<string> &permList, vector<string> &nameList) {
    vector<string> tmpVec; 

    if (nameList.size() == 0) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < permList.size(); i++){
            cout << permList.at(i) << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    else {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < nameList.size(); i++){
            tmpVec = nameList;

            permList.push_back(tmpVec[i]);
            tmpVec.erase(tmpVec.begin() + i);

            AllPermutations(permList, tmpVec);

            permList.pop_back();
        }
    }
}


int main() {
   vector<string> nameList; //create the vector the names will go into
   vector<string> permList;  //create an empty vector

   string name;
   cin >> name;  //getline doesn't need to be used because the names have no spaces
    
   while (name != "-1") {
       nameList.push_back(name);  //fill the vector with all names input
       cin >> name;
    } 

    AllPermutations(permList, nameList); //call the function with the empty vector and the filled vector

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it.  There are two main problems in your logic.

First, when you print out `cout << tmpString<< " " ;`, you do it before the recursion, and then you remove tmpString from the names.  That is the one and only time that string will be printed for it in this place throughout the recursion, as the remainder of your processing for the rest of the names happens during the recursion and it no longer knows about that string.

The second problem is that you keep creating a new tempPerm with each recursive call, so you're not "building up" a solution, but creating a vector that becomes a copy of the current nameList, which isn't helpful.

Instead, what you want to do is push the current string into permList, and make permList non-const, so the function can modify it, and pass it to the recursive call, building up the collection of strings.  When you find an empty nameList, you know it's a terminal call in the recursion and dump out the permList then.

When the recursive call returns, pop the element from the back of the permList since it was already processed and you need to make room for the next value.

Finally, for code cleanliness, you don't even need tmpString, or tempString, or to declare i before the loop.  Also, permList is an implementation detail, so callers should not have to pass in a dummy.  Instead, have a public-facing function that only takes the name list, locally creates the dummy permList, and passes both into a second function.

Here's your code with the above changes applied.  I tried to keep it as close to the original as possible while still cleaning it up.  However, I removed the input code and just hard-coded a sequence of strings.  As you can see, I got rid of the
`using namespace std;` which is semi-distasteful.  :)

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using StrVec = std::vector<std::string>;

void AllPermutationsImpl(StrVec& permList, const StrVec& nameList) { 
    if (nameList.size() == 0) {
        // we have consumed all the names, so permList is one complete answer
        for (auto& perm : permList) {
            std::cout << perm << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        StrVec tempVec;
        for (auto i = 0; i < nameList.size(); i++){
            tempVec = nameList;
            // Fix this current current item in place in the permList,
            // and recurse to handle all names that follow it. 
            permList.push_back(tempVec[i]);
            tempVec.erase(tempVec.begin() + i);
            AllPermutationsImpl(permList, tempVec);
            // We've returned from the recursion, so we have finished
            // handling all permutations with this item in this place,
            // so remove it to allow something else in its place.
            permList.pop_back();
        }
    }     
}

void AllPermutations(const StrVec& nameList) {
    StrVec permList;  
    AllPermutationsImpl(permList, nameList);
} 

// Notice, this caller does not need to worry about permList, only the names
// to use.
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   AllPermutations({"Abe", "Bella", "Charlie"});
}
```

See it live: https://godbolt.org/z/ofsW95nMG

Comment: Forgot to mention, you could be more efficient by not building up and tearing down so many vectors, but that's probably not a concern for this exercise.  Also, for "real" code you would use the standard library permutation code, but I suspect the point of this is to learn about recursion.  Good luck.